# Interesting Card game Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving, card-games

Imagine you're at a casino. The game you're playing consists of the following:

There are 52 cards, half of them are red, and the other half are black. Croupier mixes the cards and he draws two. If both of them are red, you get a point, if they are of different color, they get discarded and nobody gets a point, and if both of them are black, then the croupier gets the point.
After this, croupier mixes the cards again and he does the same. Points are given as said before. This process is then repeated until all 52 cards have been drawn.
You win the game if you get more points strictly than the house. Question is: How much money would you be willing to bet on this game?

The answer a friend of mine came up with is that you should never bet anything because you are never going to win, as the game will always result in a draw, having drawn the same number of  pair of reds as blacks.

Thing is, I haven't been able to come up with a rigourous mathematical explanation, so I was hoping someone would know how to do it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Not a mathematical remark, but I always thought that "dealer" was the term for card games.  A "croupier" handles dice games, roulette, basically everything but cards.  I could well have that wrong, of course.  Anybody know for sure?

Comment: Even without the "game will always result in a draw", you can show the the expected value of the net points is 0 by symmetry, and that the distribution is symmetrical about 0, and that there is at least 1 game that results in a net score of 0 (where the house wins), so your expected payoff is negative and you won't want to play the game (at least in expectation, which is what your phrasing is going for.)

Comment: @CalvinLin  Oh, understood.  These near-duplicates are tough and, as you say, hard to search for.  In this case, I think the solution at the duplicate is essentially equivalent to what I wrote, so better to close it off.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Still curious about Croupier v Dealer though.  Looking it up online, I read that they are "synonyms" but that they are typically divided as to game type.  Doesn't sit right though.  I'd never call a dice manager a Dealer, nor would I call a card manager a Croupier.  Can't actually think of a context where I'd regard the words as interchangeable.